# Oh My Zsh How to run multiple `omz` commands

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I have a basic script that installs and configures Oh My Zsh taking advantage of the `omz` command.

Here is a snippet:

```bash
/bin/zsh -i -c "\
omz theme set pygmalion &&\
omz plugin enable nvm &&\
omz plugin enable zsh-autosuggestions"
```

Unfortunately only the first command runs.

Even if I try to run

```bash
omz theme set pygmalion && omz plugin enable nvm && omz plugin enable zsh-autosuggestions
```

directly in my shell only the first theme command will be executed.

How to run all of those commands at once, inside of a script?

Comment: How did you verify that only the first command is executed? You don't create in your code an shell you could interact with, so you don't actually use the plugins.  You could at least add a `... && nvm ls` to test that all commands have been processed.

Comment: @user1934428 Every executed command leaves a message. Trust me I verified that they are not executed silently. I would not bother to ask a question otherway..
https://i.imgur.com/nt66bn1.png

Comment: Does `omz theme set pygmalion` have a non-zero exit status? That is enough to prevent the command following `&&` from executing. What happens if you replace `&&` with `;`?

Comment: @chepner I actually tried using `;` still not working. The only way to make every commands run in one shot is to randomly pipe them. And it breaks everything lol.
https://i.imgur.com/K5zQjdq.png

Comment: So where then is the problem? It works as advertised. It's just pointless to do it inside `zsh -i -c '....'`, since you don't create an interactive zsh where you could make use of these settings.

Comment: _How to run all of those commands at once, inside of a script?_  : I don't see how an **interactive** feature such as _autosuggestions_ could be useful inside a **script**, but for clarification, you could perhaps post a script which uses those plugins. Maybe this would make your question somewhat clearer.

Comment: @user1934428 wtf? As I said `I have a basic script that installs and configures Oh My Zsh `, and `zsh-autosuggestions` is a plugin that is part of my omz installation. Did you even read?

Comment: @AlexandreDaubricourt Strongly suggest that you delete this last comment.

Comment: «AlexandreDaubricourt: Yes, I did read it. It is just that I don't see in the example code you posted, **how** you have verified that _autosuggestions_ is not working. The trouble is that it is hard to imagine how you can use _autosuggestion_ in a meaningful way in a *script*, because this plugin is meant to be used in a shell where you are actually typing in commands, and not in a script.

Comment: @user1934428 It is a script that installs omz, as I said, and commands like `omz plugin enable` install plugins for the current user and modify your config persistently. Auto suggestion will not be used in the script itself, it just needs to be installed, through the `omz` command, executed by the script 

Comment: This is clear, but it installs the plugin inside the `zsh` child process which you are creating (by doing a `zsh -i ...`, so it means that to **use** the plugin, you can **use** the plugin only in this child process. This in turn means that you prove that the installation did not work, you would have to somehow use the plugin in this script - and I don't see any such attempt in the code you posted.

Comment: @user1934428 No. It modifies your `~/.zshrc` permanantly even after the process exits.

Comment: I did not know that `omz` modifies your .zshrc. That's creepy, but if you are happy with such a tool, it's fine.  Did you source your .zshrc aftrewards? You don't show in your question that you did.

Comment: You don't have to source explicitly. It's already handled by `omz`. Anyways my question was about chaining these commands. @user1934428

Comment: You either have to source it, or open a new zsh (which implicitly sources it). How else should your zsh process the changes? Well, one possibility would be to make the sourcing automatic, for instance using a suitable _precmd_. I don't know whether you do it. BTW, I don't know exactly what you mean by **chaining** commands. If you want to say _executing them one after the other_, you just separate them by a semicolon or a newline. But as _Gairfowl_ explains in his answer, `omz` seems to consume the current zsh process, thereby disabling the execution of the subsequent commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `omz` function runs `exec zsh` after changing the configuration in order to reload `zsh` with the changes.  That completely replaces the shell instance, which means anything else the shell was planning on doing (e.g. the commands after `&&` or `;`) will be discarded.

You can see this in a short example:

```bash
> print BEFORE; exec zsh; print AFTER
BEFORE
```

---

Some possible work-arounds.

###### Option 1 - Call `zsh` multiple times.

```bash
zsh -i -c 'omz theme set pygmalion'
zsh -i -c 'omz plugin enable nvm'
zsh -i -c 'omz plugin enable zsh-autosuggestions'
```

The `omz` function will relaunch the shell within each call, but since there is only one command in each instance, nothing will be lost when the `exec zsh` is performed.

---

###### Option 2 - Non-interactive `zsh`.

In the `omz` function, the `exec zsh` is only run in an interactive shell, so launching `zsh` without the `-i` option should allow the subsequent commands to execute.

Unfortunately, in the default `oh-my-zsh` setup, the `omz` function is set from `.zshrc` and is therefore only available in interactive shells. This means a bit more code is needed to load the function:

```bash
zsh -c "
. $ZSH/lib/cli.zsh
omz theme set pygmalion
omz plugin enable nvm
omz plugin enable zsh-autosuggestions"
```

If the `ZSH` variable isn't set when you make this call, you'll need to figure out its value (it's often `~/.oh-my-zsh/`).

---

###### Option 3 - Set `.zshrc` directly.

It appears that the `omz` calls are just changing some lines in the `.zshrc` file, so you could make those changes from the script. A simple form might look something like this:

```bash
print 'ZSH_THEME="pygmalion"
plugins+=(nvm zsh-autosuggestions)' >> ~/.zshrc
```

A more complex version could check to ensure that this isn't adding duplicate lines to the file (which is one of the things the `omz` script is doing).

---

All of this seems kinda cumbersome. You may want to ask the OMZ maintainers if there is another option for updating configurations that avoids this issue.

Comment: Option 2 is nut! Thanks for your detailed answer I learned quite a few things!

Comment: Excellent explanation. The `omz` really seems to be bizarre. One point I don't understand in your answer is your option 2: What purpose could a _theme setting_ or the _autosuggestion_ plugin possibly serve in a non-interactive shell?

Comment: @user1934428 - these options are just for the OP's configuration script; each will change `~/.zshrc` so that a future interactive shell will have the plugins or theme.